# Get The Module Extended By a Class

Tags: python

I've a class:

```
class A(SomeModule)
```

How to get the module extended by class A (SomeModule) ?

I cannot use isinstance() function to achieve this, thanks before

Comment: That example doesn't make sense.  Classes don't inherit from modules, they inherit from other classes.

Comment: I see..
this is my mistake, That's why I find it quite weird, I'm quite new in python, thanks for the answer, 
is there any way to delete this stupid question ? haha

Answer (score 2):

A module is just a static bag of classes and functions. It is not instantiable, so it is not even clear what you mean by having a class "extend" a module.

If you intend to end up with a module that has all the members of `SomeModule` and then some, create a module that imports `SomeModule` and define some more members. If you intend to end up with an instantiable class that has some (or all) of the functions in `SomeModule`, import `SomeModule` where you are defining your class, and invoke those functions from within your class methods.